# Async insertAll requests using python-api-client

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I'm using the following code to stream data from App Engine into BigQuery. Currently the requests are blocking. Is there a way of making these requests asynchronous using just the apiclient (without using the `deferred` library or similar)?

```
credentials = AppAssertionCredentials(scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery')
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
bigquery = build('bigquery', 'v2', http = http)
bigquery.tabledata().insertAll(
    projectId = PROJECT_NUMBER,
    datasetId = DATASET_ID,
    tableId = TABLE_ID,
    body = body).execute()
```

Comment: Maybe this will help https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/asynchronousrequests

Comment: @VincentBeltman Thanks, I'm familiar with and using urlfetch rpc requests. I wonder if there's a way using just `apiclient` instead of dispatching the request manually.

Comment: There is no such thing within apiclient as far as i know. I looked through the whole code actually, but I couldn't find any. That was about half a year or so. Maybe it changed.

Answer (score 1):

The Python api client (from https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/) is a synchronous client. You will have to manage asynchronous requests outside of the client.